# How to set MediaPlayer playback rate in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, media-player

I'm trying to slow down/speed up playback rates for music using the MediaPlayer. Changing `.currentPlaybackRate` does not actually change the playback rate. How would I do this correctly?

```
@IBAction func minusTempoButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    mediaPlayer.currentPlaybackRate - 0.05
    songSpeedPercentage -= 5
    speedPercentageLabel.text = "\(songSpeedPercentage)%"

    if mediaPlayer.currentPlaybackRate == 0.25 || songSpeedPercentage == 25 {
        decreaseSpeedButton.isEnabled = false
    }

    increaseSpeedButton.isEnabled = true
}

@IBAction func increaseTempoButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    mediaPlayer.currentPlaybackRate + 0.05
    songSpeedPercentage += 5
    speedPercentageLabel.text = "\(songSpeedPercentage)%"

    if mediaPlayer.currentPlaybackRate == 2.0 || songSpeedPercentage == 200 {
        increaseSpeedButton.isEnabled = false
    }

    decreaseSpeedButton.isEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: This question is not a duplicate because the duplicate post does not provide a definitive code answer. Plus the code being used is with an earlier version of Swift.  My question is also using an @IBAction rather than void. Please reopen this for an answer. I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Are you aware that you are not actually changing the `currentPlaybackRate`? Change `- 0.5` to `-= 0.5`. Make similar change for the other one.

Comment: That was a easy oversight on my part. Apologies. But that still doesn't fix my problem. I just tested it. The label and buttons function properly but the music doesn't change the rate at which it's playing. Any more advice?

Comment: I have never been able to change it using media player.